# Mysql sort order date 0000-00-00 first

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

The below MySQL query works, but not the way I like.

Some posts have a date of `0000-00-00`. How can I list those first and then the rest.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
ORDER BY posts.created DESC
```

### Example results

```
0000-00-00 - A post
0000-00-00 - Another post
2019-02-03 - New post
2011-01-01 - Old post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to add an explicit key:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
ORDER BY (p.created = '0000-00-00') DESC,
         p.created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

CREATE VIEW test1 AS
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE p.created = '0000-00-00';

CREATE VIEW test2 AS
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE p.created <> '0000-00-00'
 ORDER BY p.created DESC;

CREATE VIEW t_final AS 
( 
    SELECT * 
      FROM test1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * 
    FROM test2
)